# Can we simplify the definition of a biadjunction using coherence for bicategories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, 2-categories

In [Biequivalences in Tricategories](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/26/14/26-14abs.html),
Gurski defines a **biadjunction of bicategories** as a sextuple $(F,G,\eta,\epsilon,\Gamma,\Sigma)$ with

- $F\colon\mathcal{C}\longrightarrow\mathcal{D}$ and $G\colon\mathcal{D}\longrightarrow\mathcal{C}$ pseudofunctors;
- $\eta\colon\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{C}}\Longrightarrow G\circ F$ and $\eta\colon F\circ G\Longrightarrow\mathrm{id}_{\mathcal{D}}$ pseudonatural transformations;
- $\Gamma$ a modification as in the diagram

[image]

(where $\rho^{-1}_F$, $\alpha^{-1}_{F,G,F}$, and $\lambda_F$ are identity $1$-cells)

- $\Sigma$ is given similarly to $\Gamma$;

satisfying the *swallowtail identities*. These are quite complicated, but in a $\mathsf{Gray}$-category take the form

[image]
[image]

(these images are from the [nLab page on lax $2$-adjunctions](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax+2-adjunction))

Now, Gurski remarks in the proof of Theorem 3.2 [(page 15, last indented paragraph)](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac//volumes/26/14/26-14.pdf#page=15) that while the tricategory $\mathsf{Bicats}$ is not a $\mathsf{Gray}$-category, it has a particularly strict structure: the components of its associators and unitors are identities and their constraints are given by unique coherence cells. This simplifies things quite a bit, and naturally leads to the following question:

**Question:** Suppose that instead one defines a biadjunction to be a sextuple as above, but with $\Gamma$ a modification as in the diagram

[image]

(rather than as in

[image])

satisfying the swallowtail conditions as given for $\mathsf{Gray}$-categories. Does coherence for bicategories imply that this simplified version is equivalent¹ to the original one?

---

¹In the sense that every "complicated biadjunction" can be made into a "simple biadjunction" and vice versa, giving a bijection of sets (let's ignore things like (higher) morphisms of biadjunctions).

Comment: Surely yes: just compose with the appropriate unitor 2-cells.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @MikeShulman I thought about that for going from the "simpler $\Gamma$" to the "complicated $\Gamma$", but for some reason I was under the impression that maybe there could be more $2$-cells of the latter form. And of course there aren't! Thanks!